# Can we send View object as parameter within OnCreate() method?

Tags: java, android, methods

I'm a beginner Android developer. I'm still learning new things every day, and while learning I have heard this question quite frequently: **What will happen if we send View object as parameter within OnCreate Method?** I have searched about it but didn't find anything helpful. I just want to know is it really possible and if so then please explain the scenario.

Comment: "we send View object" -- send it to what?

Comment: I meant if I pass the View object to OnCreate() method, then what will happen. I have also requested everyone if this is really possible or not. That means I am not certain, I thought asking a question here will clear your doubts, but turns out people are more than happy to downvote. Thanks anyways.

Comment: "I meant if I pass the View object to OnCreate() method" -- I do not know what `onCreate()` method you are referring to. There are callback methods in the Android SDK named `onCreate()`, but none of them take a `View` as a parameter. You are welcome to invent your own method named `onCreate()` that happens to take a `View` as a parameter, but nothing will call it other than perhaps your own code, and so you might as well give the method a less-confusing name.

Comment: With regards to the downvote, while I did not downvote you, I am not terribly surprised that you received a downvote. If you hover your mouse over the downvote arrow, the tooltip will show that one of the reasons is "this question is unclear". Your question is unclear. Partly, that is because your question is very short. I think that your question would have had better results if you had taken the time to show some sample code, or written a few paragraphs explaining what exactly you mean and what your use case is. And your comment above does not help to clarify what you want very much.

Comment: "There are callback methods in the Android SDK named onCreate(), but none of them take a View as a parameter." -- I've got my answer now, so it's not even possible. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

oncreate() called when the activity is first created. This is where you should do all of your normal static set up: create views, bind data to lists, etc. This method also provides you with a Bundle containing the activity's previously frozen state.